# Returning Object Value Based On Property

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object that includes a variety of animals:

```
var toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}]
```

I'm wanting to return the names of the animals that are cats, only. I'm struggling to do so. Here is my attempt:

```
var cats = []
function onlyCats(array) {
  if (toonimals.animal === 'cat') {
    cats.push(toonimals.name)
  }
  return cats
}
console.log(onlyCats(toonimals));
```

Currently, it is only returning the empty array so the `.push()` method isn't working for some reason.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through the array to [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the animal. Then use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  to modify the array to return the name:

```js
var toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}];

function onlyCats(array) {
  return array.filter(a => a.animal === 'cat').map(a => a.name);
}
console.log(onlyCats(toonimals));
```

In your way with the help of [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}];

var cats = []
function onlyCats(array) {
  array.forEach(function(animal){
    if (animal.animal === 'cat') {
      cats.push(animal.name)
    }
  });
  return cats;
}
console.log(onlyCats(toonimals));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually iterate over the `toonimals` array. You can achieve this concisely with `.filter` and `.map`:

```js
var toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}]

const onlyCats = array => array
  .filter(({ animal }) => animal === 'cat')
  .map(({ name }) => name);
  
console.log(onlyCats(toonimals));
```

Or, to only iterate *once*, use `reduce`:

```js
var toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}]

const onlyCats = array => array
  .reduce((a, { name, animal }) => {
    if (animal === 'cat') {
      a.push(name);
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
console.log(onlyCats(toonimals));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}]
let op = []

toonimals.forEach(({name,animal})=>{
  if(animal === 'cat'){
    op.push(name)
  }
})

console.log(op)
```

You can also use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

by filter we get object with `animal = cat` and than we map name of each filtered element.

```js
var toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}]

let cats = toonimals.filter(({animal})=> animal ==='cat').map(({name})=>name)

console.log(cats)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter objects having `name === 'cat'` and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to transform the result and get a new array from the filtered array.

```js
const toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}];

let catOnly = Array.from(toonimals.filter(obj => obj.animal === 'cat'), animal => animal.name);

console.log(catOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one `map`, then `filter` by `Boolean` to remove `undefined`:

```js
var toonimals = [ {name: 'Itchy', animal: 'mouse'}, {name: 'Stimpy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Daffy', animal: 'duck'}, {name: 'Scratchy', animal: 'cat'}, {name: 'Ren', animal: 'dog'}, {name: 'Felix', animal: 'cat'}];

const catNames = arr => arr.map(e => { if (e.animal == "cat") return e.name }).filter(Boolean);

console.log(catNames(toonimals));
```